# How do I crop only height?

Tags: 7, media

I want to crop an image that is anchored at the center, but only crop the height.  How can this be done in Drupal 7?

EDIT: The process needs to be automated.  Basically I desire the functionality of the existing crop process for an image style, but without the requirement for having to enter a value for both width and height.

EDIT #2:  The width needs to be variable :)

Comment: I think you can add a scale by width (which doesn't require the height), then crop by the same width and the new height

Comment: You raised an important point that I missed before :)  I've updated my question to be more specific.  That's a nifty trick though.

Comment: Ah ok :) So you're looking to crop an image vertically to a certain height (center cutout), but for the original image width to stay the same? Won't the results be a wee bit unpredictable?

Comment: Unpredictable indeed, but the design I'm working with has a specific height utilized, but the width is variable.  I don't account for it if it's not in the spec :)  Now if they want to pay me to change the spec, that's another thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use custom GD methods I think.

Have a look at this module : https://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions

With the embed "Custom Actions" module you'll be able to use any gd method you want.

Add a custom filter to an image filter, and find the gd function to use.

In example, to get a B&W picture, the php code to use is :

```
return imagefilter($image->resource, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
```

Comment: This looks like it will require some research, but is so far the best possible solution I've seen.

Answer (score 2):

Just came across this, and I had a similar issue: crop an image to a fixed height, but leave the width untouched.

[ImageCache Actions](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) has a "Define Canvas" option that can take a percentage for one axis ("100% width") and a pixel measurement ("450px") for the other.

I was all set to dig in and monkey with the "Custom Actions" module when I stumbled across "Define Canvas".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today, and luckily found the [Image max size crop](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_max_size_crop) module.

> This module adds an image-style which crops an image when the image dimensions are larger then the given dimensions.
>
> In contrary to the core image style crop only one dimension is required.

In my own tests it does work as advertised. Although more accurate would be:

- ... adds an "image effect", not an "image-style".